# Language Manager Joomla 3.3.1 Url format change

Tags: .htaccess, url, joomla, multilingual, joomla3.0

We are currently using the joomla language manager in joomla 3.3.1 for the multilingual content support. It fulfills our requirements to add articles in different languages and also create menus. But a major problem is

Suppose website name is sample.com

And English is default language

Article link (english) - sample.com/content/

Article link (french)  - sample.com/fr/content/ <--- This is what i am getting with the language manager but

This is what i want  - fr.sample.com/content/

Any suggestion on how i can make it work?

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

You want to create subdomains of the third level !

To do this you need to install joomla in each subdomain and share database tables.